# Highlight entire row based on criteria using Office Script for Excel

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I have experience writing vba but work uses Excel online for multiple staff, so I have been playing with scripts and am stuck on some conditional formatting. Below is what I have so far but of course, it only highlights the cell which contains the text "Test" and I would like it to highlight the entire row.

Do I need to add another line declaring a seperate range since the condition rule only applies to Column H? I am wanting to have the entire row highlight yellow anytime "Test" is selected in Column H from the drop down box we have.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the first column in the current worksheet.
    const currentSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const firstColumn = currentSheet.getRange("H:H");  

    // Add conditional formatting based on the text in the cells.
    const textConditionFormat = 
    firstColumn.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.containsText).getTextComparison();

    // Set the conditional format to provide a green fill.
    textConditionFormat.getFormat().getFill().setColor("Yellow");

    // Apply the condition rule that the text begins with "Test".
    const textRule: ExcelScript.ConditionalTextComparisonRule = {
    operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalTextOperator.beginsWith,
    text: "Test"
    };
    textConditionFormat.setRule(textRule);
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code as text? Not as an image.

Comment: @Skin hopefully I did that correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set conditional format for all cells. Please try it.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    conditionalFormatting = selectedSheet.getRange().addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("Yellow");
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getRule().setFormula("=left($H1,4)=\"Test\"");
}
```

Comment: taller_ExcelHome this worked like a charm!!! THANK YOU